# Grub bootloader failed to boot in dual boot system after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: grub2, 12.10

I had 12.04 with my dual boot system. Yesterday I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 make bootable USB and choose Upgrade option in Installer. After installation Grub failed to boot my machine. I tried following  to fix grub bootloder . Same problem I fixed with Ubuntu 12.04 using live USB but this solution not work for Ubuntu 12.10. Now coming at exactly where this solution goes fail.

I followed  this steps after booting Live USB and opening terminal.

1) `sudo fdisk -l` to see where Linux is installed

2) `sudo mount /dev/sda9 /mnt` where sda9 is my linux partition

3) `sudo mount /dev/sda9 /mnt/boot`

4) `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`

5) `sudo chroot /mnt`  (No problems with this steps done perfectly)

6) `grub-install /dev/sda` when I type command I got error that

```
source_dir doesn't exist Please specify --target or --directory
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try the [Boot-Repair ?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu)

Comment: Oh , just answered to your question.. hah. Can you provide the link with boot-info ?

Comment: I worked with terminal so didn't get screenshot.

Comment: Boot-Repair is not a CLI program is a GUI program. Are sure you ran it ? Boot again from LiveCD-USB and run again boot-repair. It will create a boot-info link with useful informations. Edit your question and add this link.

Comment: I want to repair with just with Live USB. In 12.04 I had fixed problem with this but problem occurs with 12.10 Only

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Boot repair disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/) is the best solution in boot problems, I ever found.

Answer (score 1):

For general boot problems (even specific problems  UEFI - GPT) with grub-boot-loader you can use the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) program from a LiveCD-USB of Ubuntu.